# MouseEnter event: how to show data of one control into another?

Tags: c#, wpf

I Use Visual Studio, C# and WPF. I create a main window called `"WindowsMonopoly"` and an user control called "CasellaColore", with some properties. In the `"WindowMonopoly"` I put more of the `"CasellaColore"`. I have this situation:

```
<Monopoly:CasellaColore x:Name="Casella8" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Indice="8" ColoreCasella="Black"/>
            <Monopoly:CasellaColore x:Name="Casella9" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Indice="9" ColoreCasella="Black"/>
```

etc...

Now I want that when I put my cursor on one of the `"CasellaColore"`, this must be showed into a grid. Explaining with simple language:
When the cursor is on the `"CasellaColore"`, then show this `"CasellaColore"` into a grid into the `"WindowMonopoly"`.

I must redo "all" the Monopoly, for as a school's exercise. My knowledge of C# and WPF is limited, but I'm one of the best of my class in programming.

Comment: Basically you want to put one of the `CasellaColore` controls in the grid and change it's data source to that of the one @`MouseEnter`... I'm sure there will be some ingenious ideas if you wait a bit...

Comment: If they're in the same window, should be as simple as naming the control and calling `CurrentCasellaColore.DataContext=this.DataContext` (or `sender`'s).

Comment: What do you mean by "showing in a grid"? Do you want to display the name of the hovered user control at a specific location of a `Grid`? Then create a `TextBlock` at this location and set the `Text` property to the sender's name in the `MouseEnter` event of all `CasellaColores`.